# How to echo variable in session message of table created successfully

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have a php page having script is searching whether a table of a particular name exists or not. And if no table exists, it displays suitable message. If table exists, it adds some data to it and displays success session message. Now, I would like to display session message as `Data added to ABC (name of the chosen table) successfully`. Instead I am getting session message as `Data added to $table sucessfully`.

Please help. Following is my code -

```
<?php 
require_once("config.php");
require_once("config2.php");
$keyQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Collection where id = 
$Id"); 
$kVal = $kewyQ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$table = trim($kVal['words']);
try
{   
// Select 1 from table_name will return false if the table does not exist.
$value = $db2->query("select 1 from `$table` LIMIT 1");
}catch (PDOException $e) {
echo "$table does not exist";
exit;
}
if($value !== FALSE)
{
........
........
session_start();
$_SESSION['success'] = 'Data added to $table successfully.';
header('location:list2.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: `$_SESSION['success'] = 'Data added to '.$table.' successfully.';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Double "" quotes instead of single quotes to render variable inside string.

```
"Data added to $table successfully.";
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can you mention the documentation for the same ?

Comment: Find here http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php and you can accept the answer if helpful.

Comment: Thanks. Accepted the answer

Comment: Glad to help :).